# Kinect Color Stream to AVI Video

Tags: c#, kinect, avi

I trying to save video from Kinect.

I have WritableBitMap:

```
   //Color frame ready
    private void SensorColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get Color Frame
        using (ColorImageFrame colorFrame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
        {
            if (colorFrame != null)
            {
                colorFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(this.colorPixels);
                this.colorBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(App.KinectHelper.sensor.ColorStream.FrameWidth, App.KinectHelper.sensor.ColorStream.FrameHeight, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null);
                this.colorBitmap.WritePixels(
          new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth, this.colorBitmap.PixelHeight),
          this.colorPixels,
          this.colorBitmap.PixelWidth * sizeof(int),
          0);
            }
        }
    }
```

How to create video from this ?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/Index.html), which offers you some DLLs to convert your RGB stream to AVI